# Liferay and portlet for talend job

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, talend

I have simple Talend job. In this job i try add new Article, I invoke addArticle() method. I build job, import to Liferay and i still have the same problem. When I click Execute job in Liferay, all jobs have status: failure. When i open this job from history tab i see this error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 2    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 3    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 4    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 5    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 6    at com.savoirfairelinux.portlet.talend.util.TalendProcessThread.run(TalendProcessThread.java:119)
 7Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.liferay.portlet.journal.service.JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.addArticle(JJJJLjava/lang/String;ZDLjava/util/Map;Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;IIIIIIIIIIZIIIIIZZZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/io/File;Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/liferay/portal/service/ServiceContext;)Lcom/liferay/portlet/journal/model/JournalArticle;
 8    at routines.LiferayJournalArticlesUtil.testAddArticle(LiferayJournalArticlesUtil.java:149)
 9    at local_project.console_output_0_1.Console_OutPut.tRowGenerator_1Process(Console_OutPut.java:699)
10    at local_project.console_output_0_1.Console_OutPut.runJobInTOS(Console_OutPut.java:975)
11    ... 5 more
```

I know that something is wrong with argument list but i don't know why. I try many combination with argument and I stil have the same error.

This is link for zip with job: [DOWNLOAD](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3idjfOElBVQYjk2eVZGUzI3QWs/view)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Liferay 6.2: [Which addArticle](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/journal/service/JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.html) method do you try to call? Compare that one with the interfaces that are available and you should be able to find the problem yourself. The error message is quite precise in describing the missing method. Just use an existing one and your script should work - at least with regards to this problem.

Comment: I decided write own portlet and read content from CSV files. Now when I invoke this method everything work ok.